# Why can I omit function invocations sometimes in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, function-calls

In the following example I have 2 functions, returning int. In one case I am obliged to use function invocation brackets `()`, in other case I am prohibited to use it.

Why and how to control?

```
package kotlin.tests

import java.util.ArrayList

object MyObject {
    fun getValue(): Int {
        return 0
    }
}


fun main() {

    val arrayList : ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList()

    println(arrayList.size())
    // Expression 'size' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

    println(MyObject.getValue)
    // Function invocation 'getValue()' expected

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`size`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/size.html) is a property on the [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) interface, and not a function. That's why you can (have to) access it without parentheses.

Kotlin uses some compiler magic to [map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) its [own collection types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/Collections.kt) to the JVM types. They just decided to expose the [size](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Collections.kt#L137)  of collections as a property for some reason, and every time you use collections in Kotlin, even though their underlying implementations are classes like `java.util.ArrayList`, you see them through the interfaces defined by Kotlin.

Comment: Is this happening to every collection? If write my own collection in Java, I won't be able to call it's size as a function? Wnat if I want such magic too? How can I write my function in Java so that it will be exposed as property in Kotlin?

Comment: Take a look at the tables [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types). If you implement a Java interface listed here in one of your own classes, it will be mapped to the corresponding Kotlin interface. So for example, if you implement `java.util.Collection`, you'll have to override the `size()` method in your Java class, but see it as if it has implemented the Kotlin [Collection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/index.html) interface when using it from Kotlin code, and it will have a `size` property.

Comment: In your own classes, you can decide to use function or property access for functions that return something. If you define `size` as `fun size():Int = ...`, you'll need to use function access. If you define it as `val size get() = ...`, you can access it like a property.